# Does ensureDebugId() Really Affect Performance?

Tags: gwt

In trying to get our webapp (written in GWT) set up for automated testing, I've read/heard that using ensureDebugId() to set element id's causes the app to take a performance hit. Of course setting element attributes would cause a *small* peformance hit for the final application, but does ensureDebugId() really cause noticable differences in performance? Does it do anything else under the hood besides set element id's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It does no cause any noticeable performance hit in our 100+ screen application.
2. Do not micro optimize your application before even writing the code.
3. Turn on the `ensureDebugId` and Profile your application.
4. Turn off the `ensureDebugId` and profile your application.

**If you truly find it affecting performance in the intolerable range then take a call.**

Answer (score 0):

`ensureDebugId` will only cause performance issues if you render tons of elements in your UI, I dont think they are going to be noticeable though. If you have such as UI, probably you will notice performance problems due to other causes.

Anyway, any unneeded single thing you remove from you app will improve your app.

I would enable `ensureDebugId` only for the test environment, so you could have a different compilation profile to test your app with jenkins or whatever continuous-integration SW you were using, and another profile to produce your deliverable product.

This [thread](https://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/8d5b654e99b4c1aa) in the gwt list could be useful if you have not read yet.